# dates difference

Tags: php, mysql

I have two dates in the mysql table.

```
sample:
date1: 2011-01-01 06:40:00
date2: 2011-02-19 18:00:00
```

I need to return the difference between them, like this:

**50 days, 12 hours, 20 minutes**

How can i do this in PHP or MYSQL?

Comment: This isn't exactly a duplicate of the linked question, since it also involves fetching the dates from MySQL, which the linked question does not.

Comment: @pedro: You can do this by query , check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should do what you need:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT (date1, date2) FROM myTable;");
while (list($date1, $date2) = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $firstdate = new DateTime($date1);
    $seconddate = new DateTime($date2);
    $diff = $firstdate->diff($seconddate);
    echo $diff->d . " days, " . $diff->h . " hours, " . $diff->i . "minutes\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: $diff->m is the month. For the minutes, use $diff->i

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```
SELECT CONCAT(
FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,'2011-01-01 06:40:00', '2011-02-19 18:00:00')  / 24), ' days ',
MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,'2011-01-01 06:40:00', '2011-02-19 18:00:00'), 24), ' hours ',
MINUTE(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,'2011-01-01 06:40:00', '2011-02-19 18:00:00')), ' minutes')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [MySQL date calculations](http://mysql-tips.blogspot.com/2005/04/mysql-date-calculations.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can read about mysql DATEDIFF function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff